# If subscription is a contract to receive something, what is a contract to send something called?

Tags: word-choice, british-english, antonyms

I'm using the word *subscription* with the following meaning:

> subscription: an arrangement to receive something, typically a publication, regularly by paying in advance.

(*Definition taken from Google, I'm not sure how to link to the source*)

Basically, I'm looking for a word that is *an arrangement to **send** something*.

Does anyone have any good suggestions for what that might be?

I have thought about Producer & Publication, but they seem a little off to me. A 'Producer' can produce the *something* to send, but doesn't necessarily have to send them and a Publication seems like the *something* that is being sent.

Comment: I'd imagine it's still a subscription. You're just selling a subscription rather than buying it.

Comment: [*Publish-subscribe*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish–subscribe_pattern) is the usual name for such a bilateral arrangement. But I like @Ronan's comment - the *contract* is still a subscription, and a magazine's marketing department is concerned with how many such *subscriptions* it can sell.

Comment: I would think when you say you're selling a subscription, you are a salesman trying to sell something for a company though.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I've considered Publish/Publisher too. @DanBron that is the use case we're thinking off, but we're having trouble naming our abstracted Roles. Publisher is the overall thing that can send messages, but it's not in charge of actually sending the message. More Googling seem to point out that Publication can be both the thing produced and the process of producing the thing.[here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/publication)

Comment: @DanTemple, the organ of a newspaper (or whatever) charged with actually getting the product in people's hands is usually named "delivery". You have "delivery trucks" and "delivery networks" (or, I suppose, "paper boys" and "paper routes"). Similar roles in other industries are called "(order) *fulfillment*" or "*distribution*" -- and there are such things as "*distribution agreements*".

Comment: You don't need such a word. It is implied that, in order to receive, someone has to send. Otherwise, they won't receive anything. The subscription determines both sides of the relationship: Who sends and who receives.

Answer (score 1):

*[Fulfillment](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20fulfillment)* is the other half of subscription.
It means meeting of a requirement or condition.

It doesn't necessarily have to do with *sending* on its own, but you might say *delivery fulfillment* (because it's a contractual obligation).

It wouldn't be unusual if, in the industry, the department is any of *delivery*, *delivery fulfillment*, or *fulfillment*.

Comment: I've deleted my answer since I think this best captures the other side of the subscription contract.

Comment: But "*subscription*" is an arrangement or agreement, whereas "*fulfillment*" is an act or process. To convey the idea of an obligation, you is have to extend "*fulfillment*" in some way, like "*fulfillment contract*", which is how it's usually phrased in industry, but this isn't totally satisfying in this particular situation (as I explain in my answer).

Comment: @DanBron or *order fulfillment* which I explained as *delivery fulfillment*. A contract is a contract. *Subscription* is more or less a purchase to receive items on a schedule. If the OP wants to have *send items on a schedule*, that's scheduled delivery. But there aren't many usages for the sender to initiate a contract. The purchaser buys and receives. The vendor sells and sends.

Comment: On further reflection, it's not a "lack of obligation" that's bugging me; after all, in "fulfillment", you're fulfilling *something*: almost always discharging an obligation of some sort. No, it's that "fulfillment" (and, unfortunately, my own "*livery*") are *acts*, whereas a "subscription", in the sense sought, is an *instrument*. What we need is "an instrument representing the obligation to deliver a publication". Which, bringing us full circle, is, unfortunately, simply a "subscription" (which is, by definition, a bilateral obligation).

Comment: If you subscribe, you have a subscription. If you fulfill, you have a fulfillment. If subscription is bilateral, so is fulfillment. That is to say, in subscription, one is not going to buy if one doesn't expect to receive. In fulfillment, one is not going to deliver if one hasn't purchased.

Comment: A "subscription", in the newspaper industry, is a term of art which literally *is a contract*. It is a legal instrument. It can be legally challenged. It can have its *language* altered. It can be extended or cancelled. It can be sold forward to someone else. It is *abstract*. If your *subscription* folder (the pieces of paper which are the physical representations or manifestations of your *obligation*) catches fire, don't worry, your obligations don't evaporate along with them: your subscription still exists. If your fulfillment catches fire, you may be S.O.L. (or, at least, out of pocket).

Comment: @DanBron aside from some rather legal gray matter, in what instance are you going to initiate a contract on the sender side? "I'm going to just send this stuff to you and oh, by the way, you're obligated to pay me for it." Contracts are bilateral and the subscription fulfillment is part of the contract, just as the subscription payment is part of the contract.

Comment: Maybe a grammatical argument would be more satisfying: *subscriptions* (count noun) do not exist in one-to-one relationships with *fulfillment* (mass noun). I could have sold "*seven subscriptions* today", but you surely didn't enact "*seven fulfillments*". A single subscription can require monthly fulfillment, or ongoing fulfillment, or have an incomplete fulfillment, but a fulfillment can correspond to an incomplete subscription (because a subscription is a *legal instrument* which must be complete in order to exist [i.e. be eligible for fulfillment]).

Comment: You don't seem to understand: yes payment and delivery (*fulfillment*) are controlled  by the contract, but *the subscription **is** the contract*.

Comment: *subscription* has been poorly defined because, in order to receive something, someone has to send it. Someone doesn't just submit money into the ether and someone doesn't just send stuff. The subscription is the contract. The contract is the arrangement. The payment *and* delivery are parts of the contract/subscription. You really can't have a contract that says, "I'm going to receive stuff" if another part doesn't also say "I'm going to send stuff".

Comment: Yes, Sr Joven, so coming full circle, and going back to the very first comments (and my later ones), and answer to OP's question is (unfortunately) "a *subscription*".

Answer (score 1):

The department of a newspaper or other periodical responsible for getting the product into people's hands is typically called "***Delivery***" (whence "*delivery trucks*", "*delivery routes*", and so on).

But "delivery" is an act, not an agreement, and also lacks the ongoing aspect of "*subscription*". In other industries, we have such things as "***distribution agreements***", and "***fulfillment contracts***", but there the "arrangement" idea is explicit, unlike "*subscription*", where the concept of agreement is tacit and subsumed into the larger definition.

So, since these terms are not an improvement, we might as well stick with our periodical metaphor. Turning back to "*delivery*", then, we notice it has an embedded concept which may be of use: "de-*livery*".

"[***Livery***](http://i.word.com/idictionary/livery)" is defined, in part, as:

> *1 archaic :  the **apportioning of provisions** especially to servants :  allowance*
>
> *4 :  the act of **delivering legal possession** of property*
>
> *5 a :  the feeding, stabling, and care of horses for pay*

That is, *livery*, at least in an archaic sense, is the "**the distribution of what is properly due** (because of a legal, commercial, or social *arrangement*".

As I said,  however, that's an obsolete sense for the term. Perhaps the closest modern equivalent is an "***allowance***":

> [***allowance***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/allowance): *A sum of money *paid regularly* to a person, typically to meet specified needs or expenses.*